# Get headers infos from redirrected page

Tags: php, arrays, http, header, http-headers

So basicaly I'm trying to get some informations off several pages' headers and to do so i'm using get_headers(). Now as long as the http response is 200, thats fine no problem the array show informations like Content-Type being a key and that's good enough for me I can check it's value.

The issue shows when the response code is 301 in which case the array becomes a multi layers array and this is the end of it for me...I cannot figure out how to easily get to the Content-Type value (I dont care about what key it is as long as I get the value obviously).

I thgouth I could run several loops checking the array values one by one but that seems to be a massive script for such a small looking issue.

So my question is : is there anyway to either flatten the array I get as an output (array below), or is there a way native to php to look for a regular expression within a multi layers array ?

301 :

```
array(12) {
    [0] = > string(30)"HTTP/1.0 301 Moved Permanently" ["Date"] = > array(2) {
        [0] = > string(29)"Thu, 06 Feb 2014 13:04:19 GMT" [1] = > string(29)"Thu, 06 Feb 2014 13:04:20 GMT"
    }["Server"] = > array(2) {
        [0] = > string(6)"Apache" [1] = > string(6)"Apache"
    }["Vary"] = > array(2) {
        [0] = > string(22)"Cookie,Accept-Encoding" [1] = > string(22)"Accept-Encoding,Cookie"
    }["Set-Cookie"] = > array(3) {
        [0] = > string(200)"wordpress_27e1f2dfbb852bd4e4295b075bfa297f=%7C1392901460%7C6714e772e8aadf7ef19238b8c45faaf5; expires=Fri, 21-Feb-2014 01:04:20 GMT; path=/wp-content/plugins; domain=www.domain.com; httponly" [1] = > string(190)"wordpress_27e1f2dfbb852bd4e4295b075bfa297f=%7C1392901460%7C6714e772e8aadf7ef19238b8c45faaf5; expires=Fri, 21-Feb-2014 01:04:20 GMT; path=/wp-admin; domain=www.domain.com; httponly" [2] = > string(192)"wordpress_logged_in_27e1f2dfbb852bd4e4295b075bfa297f=%7C1392901460%7Ccd60c9eaeab6cf8e770eb7a121440e5f; expires=Fri, 21-Feb-2014 01:04:20 GMT; path=/; domain=www.domain.com; httponly"
    }["X-Pingback"] = > string(43)"http://www.domain.com/xmlrpc.php" ["Location"] = > string(38)"http://www.domain.com/acces" ["Connection"] = > array(2) {
        [0] = > string(5)"close" [1] = > string(5)"close"
    }["Content-Type"] = > array(2) {
        [0] = > string(24)"text/html; charset=UTF-8" [1] = > string(24)"text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    }[1] = > string(15)"HTTP/1.1 200 OK" ["Cache-Control"] = > string(26)"max-age=3, must-revalidate" ["WP-Super-Cache"] = > string(31)"Served supercache file from PHP"
}
```

Just in case you need it, here's my code :

```
public function checkhttp() {
        if ($_SESSION['started'] == 1) {
            $headers = @get_headers($_SESSION['next_page'], 1);
        //$headers['Content-Type'] will return the expected value if response is 200    
            if(!preg_match('/(200|202|300|301|302)/', $headers[0]) || !preg_match('/(html)/', $headers['Content-Type'])){
                $_SESSION['next_page'] = $_SESSION['page_list'][0];
                $_SESSION['page_list_done'][] = $_SESSION['page_list'][0] . ' ----- FAIL TO CONNECT. Debug purpose : ' . $headers[0] . $headers['Content-Type'];
                array_splice($_SESSION['page_list'], 0, 1);
                foreach ($_SESSION['page_list_done'] as $value) {
                    echo $value . '<br />';
                }
                echo $headers[0] . '<br />';
                var_dump($headers);
                header( "refresh:2;url=" . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] );
                exit;
            }
        }
    }
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those who ask themselves the same question, the variable you looking for is `$headers[Content-Type][0]`